Samesite cookies set to none but same domain
I'm checking my website cookies values, in order to prepare it for the next google chrome privacu .
I found some cookies that have samesite value to none , but when I check the domain it's the same as the website  ( for example website example.com. the domain is also example.com )
I read that samesite = none is for third party cookies. but here the same site is used.
the cookies keys are : TC_PRIVACY an TC_PRIVACY_CENTER. I don't know for what they stand ? ( tag-commander ? )
Is this normal ?

"I read that samesite = none is for third party cookies." - that's a bit of a weird way of phrasing it. It applies, if/when the cookie would be sent in a cross-origin request.

The cookie names indicate they probably belong to / are set by a service called TrustCommander, which appears to be some sort of cookie consent banner.

So it's a first party cookie , no risk for it to be blocked in chrome when the chrome sandbox privacy feature will be released

@C3roe does this mean if third party cookies will be blocked , trustCommander should propose an alternative to samesite=none ?

https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox?hl=en

"does this mean if third party cookies will be blocked , trustCommander should propose an alternative to samesite=none ?" - why? You said these cookie were said for the domain you are on to begin with - so they aren't 3rd party then in that context.
